# React update components issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 3 components: App, CV and EXP_FORM.
APP have state where i store data from EXP_FORM and after that i render it by CV component. Issue is when i type in input fields in EXP_FORM CV updates it in one step behind.
for example: if i type in position input field in EXP_FORM "soft" in CV i will got "sof"

**app.js**

```
import React,{Component} from "react";
import CV from "./components/CV"
import EXP_FORM from "./components/Exp_form";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      email: '',
      phone: '',
      //educationLs:[],
      experienceLs:[{id:0}],
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleExp = this.handleExp.bind(this)
  }

  form_style = {
    display: 'grid'
  }

  handleChange(event){
    this.setState({
      [event.target.id] : event.target.value
    })
  }

  handleExp = (exp) => {
    this.setState({
      experienceLs: this.state.experienceLs.map(u => u.id !== exp.id ? u : exp),
    })
  }

  render(){
    const {name, email, phone, educationLs,experienceLs} = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        <form style={this.form_style}>
          <label htmlFor='nameInput'>Name: </label>
          <input type='text' id='name' onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          
          <label htmlFor='emailInput'>Email: </label>
          <input type='text' id='email' onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          
          <label htmlFor='phoneInput'>Phone: </label>
          <input type='text' id='phone' onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        </form>
        <EXP_FORM id={0} callback={this.handleExp}/>
        <div>
        <CV name={name} email={email} phone={phone} exp={experienceLs} />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

**EXP_FORM.js**

```
import React from 'react'

class EXP_FORM extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            id: props.id,
            position: '',
            company: '',
            city:'',
            from: '',
            to: ''
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }

    form_style = {
        display:'grid'
    }
  
    handleChange(event){
      this.setState({
        [event.target.name] : event.target.value
      })

    }

    onTrigger = () => {
        this.props.callback(this.state)
    }

    onChangeEvents = (event) => {
        this.handleChange(event)
        this.onTrigger()
    }

    render(){
        const {position} = this.state
        return(
            <div>
                <form style={this.form_style} onChange={this.onChangeEvents}>
                    <label htmlFor='position'>Position: {position}</label>
                    <input type='text' name='position'/>
            
                    <label htmlFor='company'>Company: </label>
                    <input type='text' name='company'/>

                    <label htmlFor='city'>City: </label>
                    <input type='text' name='city'/>

                    <label htmlFor='from'>From: </label>
                    <input type='text' name='from'/>

                    <label htmlFor='to'>To: </label>
                    <input type='text' name='to'/>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default EXP_FORM
```

**CV.js**

```
import React from "react"

const CV = (props)=>{
    const exp = props.exp.map((e) =>
    <div key={e.id}>
        <p>position: {e.position}</p>
        <p>in {e.company}</p>
        <p>From {e.from} until {e.to}</p>
        <p>city:{e.city}</p>
    </div>);
    
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Name: <span>{props.name}</span></h1>
            <h1>Email: <span>{props.email}</span></h1>
            <h1>Phone: <span>{props.phone}</span></h1>
            <h1>Experience:</h1>
            {exp}
        </div>
    )
}

export default CV
```

whats wrong ?

Comment: seems to work fine for me

Comment: but its dont work properly